# Data marker symbol for WebApp ArcGIS widget

Tags: javascript, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget, arcgis-custom-widget

I am building a web application using Web AppBuilder from ArcGIS where I want user to be able to select the marker type as they try to import CSV.

A popup which allows them to select a symbol and if possible size and color of the symbol then plot the points on the map.

Is there any widget for that? If yes, then what is the link to download it?